# body not 100% using ::after pseudo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a texture background image with another image on top of that using `body::after`. When I scroll down the page the top image eventually get's covered up.

I can use `body { overflow: auto }` to fix it but then my `masthead` and `navbar` elements don't get the `minify` class added to them. The `minify` class makes the `masthead` smaller, and sticks it to the top of the page.

Is there another way to fix it without using `overflow: auto`?

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Draven/sg64hzsn/)

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="distance"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header id="masthead" class="masthead" role="banner">
      <h1 class="h-mast"><a href="" title="Title">Title<span class="slogan">SubTitle</span></a></h1>
    </header>
    <nav id="navbar" class="nav mainnav">
      <ol class="nav-1">
        <li class="list-nav-1 here"><a href="" title="Home">home</a></li>
        <li class="list-nav-1"><a href="nav_2/" title="Nav 2">Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="list-nav-1"><a href="nav_3/" title="Nav 3">Nav 3</a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
    <main id="main" class="main" role="main" tabindex="-1">
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #012730 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAO0lEQVQYGWNkgAJGbcv/MDaI/n/1OCMyn3g2uknIOpHlmJAl8LGprxCfbShy8CBAdjhIBfnBg2I+Hg4AFewK0YgdlRIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;
  font: normal 12px/1 Optima, Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

body:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/2xkWw65.png') 50% 180px no-repeat fixed;
  opacity: 0.20;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var value = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (value > 60) {
    $('#masthead').addClass('minify');
    $('#main').addClass('minify');
  } else {
    $('#masthead').removeClass('minify');
    $('#main').removeClass('minify');
  }
  if (value > 31) {
    $('#navbar').addClass('minify');
  } else {
    $('#navbar').removeClass('minify');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of absolute positioning with fixed background, you can use fixed positioning:

```css
body::after {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var value = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (value > 60) {
    $('#masthead').addClass('minify');
    $('#main').addClass('minify');
  } else {
    $('#masthead').removeClass('minify');
    $('#main').removeClass('minify');
  }
  if (value > 31) {
    $('#navbar').addClass('minify');
  } else {
    $('#navbar').removeClass('minify');
  }
});
$('.post').each(function(index) {
  var delay = $(this).attr('data-delay');
  if (typeof delay !== typeof undefined && delay !== false) {
    $(this).css('animation', 'flipInX 2s ' + delay);
    $(this).css('-webkit-animation', 'flipInX 2s ' + delay);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #012730 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAO0lEQVQYGWNkgAJGbcv/MDaI/n/1OCMyn3g2uknIOpHlmJAl8LGprxCfbShy8CBAdjhIBfnBg2I+Hg4AFewK0YgdlRIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;
  font: normal 12px/1 Optima, Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
body:after {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/2xkWw65.png') 50% 180px no-repeat fixed;
  opacity: 0.20;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
}
*:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
a {
  color: #6fc3cc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #23848f;
}
[class|=nav] {
  list-style: none;
}

/*masthead*/
.masthead {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 1%;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #23848f;
}
.masthead .h-mast {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 42px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.h-mast a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 99px;
  padding: 10px 0 16px 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
.h-mast a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.slogan {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.masthead.minify,
#navbar.minify .nav-1 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px;
}
.masthead.minify {
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #012730;
}
.masthead.minify .h-mast a {
  height: auto;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0;
}
.masthead.minify .h-mast .slogan {
  display: none;
}
#navbar.minify .nav-1 {
  top: 14px;
}

/* Navigation Bar */
[class|=list-nav] {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
[class|=list-nav] a,
[class|=list-nav] a:link,
[class|=list-nav] a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}
[class|=list-nav] a:hover,
[class|=list-nav] a:active,
[class|=list-nav].here a {
  text-decoration: underline
}
.mainnav .nav-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  right: 1%;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
}

/*main*/
.main {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
.main.minify {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.main-1 .h-1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1.14em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #23848f;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-2,
.main-3 {
  min-height: 400px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
[class|=h] {
  margin-bottom: 42px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
}
.main-2.no_content,
.main-3.no_content {
  display: none;
}

/*animate*/
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both
}
.animated.bounceIn,
.animated.bounceOut,
.animated.flipOutX,
.animated.flipOutY {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
  animation-duration: .75s
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px)
  }
}
@keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px)
  }
}
.flipInX {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
  animation-name: flipInX
}

/* Home Page */
.homepage .main-1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.homepage .main-2 {
  min-height: 50px;
}
.homepage .main-3 {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.homepage .post {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px;
}
.homepage .post .h-1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 110%;
  margin: 14px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.homepage .post .entry {
  padding: 0 10%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="homepage">
  <div id="distance"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header id="masthead" class="masthead" role="banner">
      <h1 class="h-mast"><a href="" title="Title">Title<span class="slogan">SubTitle</span></a></h1>
    </header>
    <nav id="navbar" class="nav mainnav">
      <ol class="nav-1">
        <li class="list-nav-1 here"><a href="" title="Home">home</a></li>
        <li class="list-nav-1"><a href="nav_2/" title="Nav 2">Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="list-nav-1"><a href="nav_3/" title="Nav 3">Nav 3</a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
    <main id="main" class="main" role="main" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="main-1">
      </div>
      <div class="main-2">
      </div>
      <div class="main-3">
        <h1 class="h-1">Services</h1>
        <article class="post flipInX animated" data-delay=".2s">
          <h1 class="h-1">Service 1</h1>
          <div class="entry">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vestibulum, lectus id sollicitudin mattis, quam tortor lobortis orci, sed iaculis mi nulla non ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas. Donec non felis mollis, congue neque eu, rhoncus libero. Nunc ut mattis ante.</div>
        </article>
        <article class="post flipInX animated" data-delay=".4s">
          <h1 class="h-1">Service 2</h1>
          <div class="entry">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vestibulum, lectus id sollicitudin mattis, quam tortor lobortis orci, sed iaculis mi nulla non ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas. Donec non felis mollis, congue neque eu, rhoncus libero. Nunc ut mattis ante.</div>
        </article>
        <article class="post flipInX animated" data-delay=".6s">
          <h1 class="h-1">Service 3</h1>
          <div class="entry">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vestibulum, lectus id sollicitudin mattis, quam tortor lobortis orci, sed iaculis mi nulla non ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas. Donec non felis mollis, congue neque eu, rhoncus libero. Nunc ut mattis ante.</div>
        </article>
        <article class="post flipInX animated" data-delay=".8s">
          <h1 class="h-1">Service 4</h1>
          <div class="entry">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vestibulum, lectus id sollicitudin mattis, quam tortor lobortis orci, sed iaculis mi nulla non ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas. Donec non felis mollis, congue neque eu, rhoncus libero. Nunc ut mattis ante.</div>
        </article>
        <article class="post flipInX animated" data-delay=".10s">
          <h1 class="h-1">Service 5</h1>
          <div class="entry">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vestibulum, lectus id sollicitudin mattis, quam tortor lobortis orci, sed iaculis mi nulla non ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas. Donec non felis mollis, congue neque eu, rhoncus libero. Nunc ut mattis ante.</div>
        </article>
        <article class="post flipInX animated" data-delay=".12s">
          <h1 class="h-1">Service 6</h1>
          <div class="entry">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vestibulum, lectus id sollicitudin mattis, quam tortor lobortis orci, sed iaculis mi nulla non ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas. Donec non felis mollis, congue neque eu, rhoncus libero. Nunc ut mattis ante.</div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Great answer. Never used `position: fixed` before :s